# Angular supported version format

Tags: angular, build, version

I am quite new to Angular builds, when updating our package.json from

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
```

version 0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0 format & performing the `ng build` it fails with

```
added 1 package from 3 contributors in 0.146s
npm WARN Invalid version: "0.0.0.0"
```

If its changed back to 0.0.0, it builds without any issues.
Is there any standard that allows only x.x.x versioning in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Angular version numbers have three parts: major.minor.patch. For example, version 7.2.11 indicates major version 7, minor version 2, and patch level 11.

I found it in angular documentation. they only support Major release, Minor release, and patch release. it only supports x.x.x.

you can find more about versioning [here](https://angular.io/guide/releases#angular-versioning)

Comment: Is this only relevant for angular dependencies or also for application that we build? 
The https://angular.io/guide/releases#preview-releases link shows it can have 8.1.0-rc.0, which is actually x.x.x.x versioning. Or is it supported for release candidate & next versions?

Comment: for RC or next version, you must mention 'next' or 'rc', so it a kind of special case as this is not making it simply x.x.x.x, it makes either x.x.x-rc.x or x.x.x-next.x